# How do I structure a JSON Schema to add a rule comparing two fields

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I have been studying docs and examples at https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/
My question is, suppose I have a form that asks MIN_AGE and MAX_AGE.
How do I set up a schema rule to ensure that MAX_AGE > MIN_AGE?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, JSON Schema doesn't define a way to make comparative assertions on JSON data.  There has been [a lot of discussion](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/labels/%24data) on a potential `$data` keyword, but no decisions have been made on it for various reasons.

Happily, with the introduction of vocabularies with draft 2019-09, you can define your own keywords.  You'll also have to provide some logic to whatever implementation you use so that it can evaluate your new keywords.